# How do I request my fast API from Python?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I am running my fastapi via Docker, here is the main.py

```
import sys
from fastapi import FastAPI
from src.redactor import DSARRedaction

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def run_redaction():
    DSARRedaction("kulveer").run_redaction()
    return {"message": "Redaction Completed"}
```

and here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y python3-opencv
# Install dependencies for textract
RUN apt-get install -y ghostscript python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev antiword unrtf poppler-utils flac ffmpeg lame libmad0 libsox-fmt-mp3 sox libjpeg-dev swig \
libpulse-dev zlib1g-dev qpdf
RUN apt -y install tesseract-ocr
RUN apt -y install libtesseract-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg

EXPOSE 50

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "50"]
```

I am trying to run the following python script as I just want to be able to get the URL via python without having to click on it.

```
import requests

requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:50/')
```

But every time I try to run that code to request the API, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f34d008fca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=50): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f34d008fca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 3, in <module>
    requests.Session().get('http://0.0.0.0:50')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=50): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f34d008fca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Try `requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:50/')`

Comment: @asanoop24it gives the same error but with (host='127.0.0.1', port=50). The fastapi info is INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:50 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: Can you check your logs on docker side? Is your API even getting the request?

Comment: No it's not getting the request at all

Comment: How are you running the docker container? Can you paste that command here as well or the `docker-compose.yml` if you are using that to start the container?

Comment: Try a port higher than 1024. Low ports are traditionally restricted.

Comment: Also, you aren't showing how you're starting the Docker container. You will need `-P` to publish all the `EXPOSE`d ports.

Comment: So I'm running the docker container with:
docker build -t redactor-api ./api
docker run -p 50:50 redactor-api

Comment: @AKX same error with port 1025

Comment: The fastapi is working because I can go to http://0.0.0.0:50/ and the API code runs, I just cant seem to connect via requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:50/')

Answer (score 0):

Access your endpoint at `http://localhost:50` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:50` so it should be

```
import requests

requests.get('http://localhost:50/')
```

Comment: Without this line, the API won't start at all.

Comment: @asanoop24, its worked for me in the past also stated here: https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker/issues/11

Comment: In that github issue, the official docker image of FastAPI is being used `FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7`, which is why the `CMD` line is not required there. But that is not the case here.

Comment: oh totally missed he’s not using that

Comment: Same error with local host:  `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fac6245fca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Comment: @Kelly why does it say `port=80`?

Comment: I just tried changing it to port 80, same code

Comment: If I do curl http://localhost:80 in my terminal it works as well

Comment: does anyone have any solution to this ?